# How many recievers per cycle in mail queue?

Tags: magento2, newsletter, queue

Before pushing the **send button**, I would like to know, how many **mailrecievers** the queue handles **per cycle**? Does it send to everybody on the list at one time, or does it go more gently with, lets say, 50 per batch? And, is so, are there any ways to configure the number.

I'm a bit worried if the server has to handle thousands of mails in one go ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **depends on Server** else if you press a Send button then if you have 10k receivers then it will send all of them.

So if you have many receivers in queue then you have to be careful else server's email limitations will be over in just one press.

Comment: And there is no way to adjust the numbers?

Comment: Right! No way !